Adding electrical outlet
I have a toggle switch. It controls a gfci outlet. The metal box and conduit is the ground. There is no ground wire. I want to add an outlet after the gfci outlet. I want to cut hole and use romex. Should I use metal or plastic receptacle box? And what do I do with grounding wire in the romex?

Are you planning to cut a hole in the wall or cut a hole in the box?

Either metal or plastic box.  There are pros and cons to each.  Metal boxes and self grounding receptacles do not need the ground wire attached to the receptacle.  Plastic boxes do.

I’m cutting drywall

Where are you located? Some jurisdictions require the use of (metal) conduit and ban plain NM in walls.

At the GFCI end of the Romex connect the ground wire to the box. There should be a tapped and drilled hole for the purpose, commonly 10-32 size.
You can use either a metal or engineered resin box for the new receptacle. In a metal box you connect the box, Romex ground and receptacle ground together. (The box will have a drilled and tapped hole for a ground screw. Install a pigtail there.) For a receptacle in a plastic box the Romex ground goes directly to the ground screw on the device.

So right now I’ll cut hole in drywall and add plastic box. I want to make sure I’m clear on this. Romex ground wire to outlet(plug) ground screw in new plastic box. Then attach romex ground other end to gfci outlet screw itself or the gfci outlet metal box ground screw.

You want to connect the Romex ground to the metal box screw, you don't want to depend on the GFCI outlet to provide the ground connection via the box. A common approach is to install a pigtail on the box screw, a pigtail on the receptacle screw, and then twist together the two pigtails and the Romex ground and install a wire nut on the three wires. Do make sure that the ground wires do not contact anything inappropriate when everything is installed in either box.

There are also self-grounding outlets.

@Huesmann - Self-grounding devices do ground themselves when properly installed in a grounded metal box. You do not want to depend on a self-grounded device to provide a ground to downstream circuits. NEC 250.148(B) sayeth: "The arrangement of grounding connections shall be such that the disconnection or the removal of a receptacle, luminaire, or other device fed from the box does not interfere with or interrupt the grounding continuity."

The OP wants to add a single outlet.  If that outlet is self-grounding, and s/he uses a metal box, with the ground wire connected to the box, s/he doesn't need to use a pigtail to ground the outlet too.

@Huesmann - True enough. The OP did comment "So right now I’ll cut hole in drywall and add plastic box."
